# Manipulate every nth image using glob.glob

Tags: python, image-processing

I was wondering what is the bast way to use glob.glob in python to manipulate every nth image, lets say I have a folder of ten images and I want to invert every second image.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
import glob

def main():
    for name in glob.glob('*.png'):

        im = Image.open(name)
        im_invert = ImageOps.invert(im)
        im_invert.save('New' + name, quality=100)
main()
```

Comment: you can do `for name in glob.glob('*.png')[::2]`

Answer (score 0):

It highly depends on how your files are sorted (or how you would like to see your files sorted).

Plus, `glob.glob` provides a list of unsorted file names (see [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html)).

Comment: thats no problem, because even though the list is unsorted, that unsorted list is always the same for the same sized group of files with the same naming profile

Comment: OK, if you don't care about the order then `glob.glob('*.png')[::2]` or `glob.glob('*.png')[1::2]` will do the job.